# URL shortening for AWS S3 Bucket data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url-shortener

For my website, i am storing user data in **Amazon S3**. But the problem is my amazon s3 link is very length and I want to **shorten** the URL.

Anybody knows how to get shorten URL from AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't get something like this from AWS.
You can chose to use something that's already out there and proven to work to shorten the url or depending on your requirements you're gonna have to build your own.